# jQuery- Add text to same line of each radio input

Tags: javascript, jquery, radiobuttonlist

So I am trying to make a dynamic quiz and am struggling with adding text to my radio inputs.  I use a for loop to make several radio inputs.  I would like the text to be on the same line as each radio choice, but I cannot accomplish this.

When I use `append()` it creates a new line then adds the text.

```
for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            $('#target').append('<input type="radio" name="radioName"/>')
            $('#target').append('<p>My text here</p>');
```

When I use the `label for` html attribute, it adds the text at the end of all the radios.

```
for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            $('#target').append('<input type="radio" name="radioName"/>').after("<label for='radio'>text here</label>");
```

Here is my jsFiddle showing the example: http://jsfiddle.net/tCkuF/2/

Ideally I would like to add a variable that represents an object as the text so it changes automatically as the quiz is taken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is recommended to use a list element in such cases

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="question"></div>
    <div id="target">
        <ul id="options">

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also give styles

```
#options{
    list-style:none;
    list-style-type:none;
}
```

Then add `li` element. Give proper `id` for using `for` attribute

```
var $li = $("<li>").appendTo("#options");
$li.append('<input id="option' + (j+1) + '" type="radio" name="question' + i + '" value="' + allQuestions[i].correctAnswer + '"/>');
$li.append("<label for='option" + (j+1) + "'>test: label for adds all to the end    </label>");
```

demo : http://jsfiddle.net/tCkuF/6/

Answer (score 2):

Your desired output can be achieved by simply adding a div wrapper around the `radio` & 'label'. Check this [out](http://jsfiddle.net/tCkuF/4/):

```
$(function () {
var i = 0;
var allQuestions = [{
    question: "What is 4x6?",
    choices: [46, 15, 25, 24],
    correctAnswer: 3
}, {
    question: "What is 21x 21?",
    choices: [441, 2121, 388],
    correctAnswer: 0
}, {
    question: "Which number is prime?",
    choices: [1, 5, 10, 39],
    correctAnswer: 1
}, {
    question: "What is 65/5",
    choices: [3, 31, 12, 13, 21],
    correctAnswer: 3
}];

function populateQuestion() {
    $("#question").text(allQuestions[i].question); //add question
    var $target = $('#target'),
        j = 0;
    //add radio and answer choices
    for (j; j < allQuestions.length; j++) {

        (function (idx) {

            var html = '<div class="answerRow"><input class="answerRadio" type="radio" name="question' + idx + '" value="' + allQuestions[idx].correctAnswer + '"/><label class="answerRadioLabel"  for="question' + idx + '">test: label for adds all to the end    </label>';
            $target.append(html);
        })(j);
    }
}

populateQuestion();


}); //onload jQuery close
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove ‍‍‍`<p>` tag and add an extra `<br/>` to each line

```
$('#target').append('test append creates a line space<br/>');
```

check demo at http://jsfiddle.net/tCkuF/3/